# WiX WebSite creates second duplicate binding when ConfigureIfExists set to yes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have an installer I am modifying where we are modifying a web site in IIS.  The requirements state that the end user must create the site first in IIS.  We read the site information they choose from a dropdown in the installer for their site, and store the information in properties in WiX.

I have a WebSite element under a component, and have the ConfigureIfExists set to yes.  A lot of this seems to be working great, it resets the directory of the site to where the website is on the drive.

The problem is that when I check the set up in IIS, the web site is not started, even when I have AutoStart = yes and StartOnInstall = yes.  The problem I am seeing is that, since it is an existing web site, it creates a duplicate binding for the site, same port and everything, which is causing the site not to run.

Does anyone know why this is happening, or how to resolve it?  I need it to not duplicate the binding so that the web site can be restarted when installation is complete.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: No, I have not.  I considered Yan's suggestion below, but my manager and I decided we would wait for the official 3.6 release to test the IIS fixes.

Comment: Also having the problem of Wix adding duplicate bindings on an already existing website, and not starting it.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to try this scenario with [WiX v3.6](http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/) (take the latest available build). There were lots of fixes in IIS7 extension, and it's very likely your problem will just go away.

EDIT: now WiX 3.6 is in official beta. It is quite stable and contains lots of fixes to IIS extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I was able to work around it with the following method, but be advised, it is kind of a hack.

For my existing website, I match it on SiteId and set whatever configuration properties I want to change with the WebDirProperties attribute.  Then, in the iis:WebAddress element, I set the Port number to some unused port (I used 8081).  This will add an extra http binding in IIS7 (as you saw in your question).  Then, I create a custom action that I run before InstallFinalize.  The custom action basically loops through the site Bindings, looks for the one that matches the bogus port that I entered in wix and deletes it.  Then the custom action starts the website and everything is good.

This was the only way I could find to get it to work in Wix 3.5.  It is not the best method, but it worked for me.